# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE gives fatal error, but works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysqli

The problem is that LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE works in phpmyadmin, but gives a fatal error when I try it in php.

In phpmyadmin my line is is this.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:/sam.csv' INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (`aa`, `bb`, `cc`)
```

And that inserted 200000 lines in about 3 seconds.
In php I tried this:

```
$dbname="test";
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','',$dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');
if($db->connect_errno){
    die('There is a problem connecting.');
}


echo "Starting";
        $query="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:/sam.csv' INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (`aa`, `bb`, `cc`)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        echo '<br>'.$query;
        $stmt->execute();
        if (!$stmt) {throw new Exception($db->error);}
echo "Ending";
```

Unfortunately this gives me a fatal error every time.
There is a table called `test` and the field names are correct.

The error is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Normally this error occurs if you mis-spell a table name, or column, so I don't understand this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `echo $db->error;` or maybe `echo $stmt->error;`  before the `execute()`. Is `e:` a mapped drive?  Doubtful that the webserver user has it mapped.

Comment: echoing the error gives me no more information. I tried both by the way. I am still getting the fatal error. E is the path to the file, which works in phpmyadmin, but not in php. I am using wampserver btw. I also tried the file in the same location also, without the E:, but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer but not quite the answer I was looking for. Apparently LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE does not work with a prepared statement.

Also good news is that the data does not need sanitizing as it is imported as text, or numbers, and is safe.

```
$query="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'e:/sam.csv' INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (`aa`, `bb`, `cc`)";
if (!($stmt = $db->query($query))) {
        echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
};
```